# Dotnet run - A compatible SDK version was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to run my asp.net core app as a host, I have several .Net core sdks installed and my global json file points to an available sdk, but it still gives me the above error.

an observation I have made is that If I use 2.1.400 instead of 2.1.4 in global.json it works fine, but that is not available on our team city pipeline and also I am not able to find and download 2.1.4 on the internet it seems that only 2.1.400 is available.
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: SDK 2.1.4 is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.0): scroll down to v2.0.5 and you'll find the SDK 2.1.4 downloads. It's a bit confusing as SDK 2.1.4 is for .NET Core 2.0 and *not* .NET Core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is VS and dotnet core framework together problem.

Scenario 1 for (VS):

> steps to follow
>
> 1. Update VisualStudio
> 2. Delete .vs folder
> 3. Restart PC
> 4. Run VisualStudio as administrator

This is what helped me.

Scenario 2 (VS):

> Write `PM> ls` and check if the VS package manager is a corect dir, If
>   not `cd folder` and try again. If not working go to Scenario 1.

Scenario 3(non-VS):

> Copy your whole repository to C:/repo folder and try again.

**If all of those wont work reinstall and update .NET core 2.1 framework.**

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version 2.1.4 -my
```

`-my` will allow you to have multiple versions installed.